# Extract URLs recursively from website archives in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I want to crawl the data from http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms, all the urls are archived based on date, month and year, first to get the urls list I am using the code from https://github.com/FraPochetti/StocksProject/blob/master/financeCrawler/financeCrawler/spiders/urlGenerator.py, modified the code for my website as,

```
import scrapy
import urllib    
def etUrl():
    totalWeeks = []
    totalPosts = []
    url = 'http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms'
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(text=data)
    months = hxs.xpath('//ul/li/a').re('http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms/\\d+-\\d+/news.cms')
    admittMonths = 12*(2013-2007) + 8
    months = months[:admittMonths]
    for month in months:
        data = urllib.urlopen(month).read()
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(text=data)
        weeks = hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="weeks"]/li/a').re('http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms/\\d+-\\d+/news/day\\d+\.cms')
        totalWeeks += weeks
        for week in totalWeeks:
            data = urllib.urlopen(week).read()
            hxs = scrapy.Selector(text=data)
            posts = hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="archive"]/li/h1/a/@href').extract()
            totalPosts += posts
            with open("eturls.txt", "a") as myfile:
                for post in totalPosts:
                    post = post + '\n'
                    myfile.write(post)

etUrl()
```

saved file as `urlGenerator.py` and ran with the command `$ python urlGenerator.py`
I am getting no result, could someone assist me how to adopt this code for my website use case or any other solution?

Comment: is there an invocation of `etUrl()`, traditionally guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__": etUrl()` type structure?

Comment: it's also **VERY WEIRD** to install Scrapy but then use `urllib` based request-response; arguably, 50% of Scrapy's power lies in how it deals with that whole process -- including having well defined callbacks to avoid the 4-deep indentation you have going on there

Comment: I took the liberty of cleanup up your post a bit, since I assume you didn't mean to be calling `etUrl()` recursively at the bottom...

Comment: However, look at the code that you modified, it looks like the `for` loops are not nested the way you've shown it.  Is the code you posted actually your real code?  In Python indentation matters *a lot* so please make sure that what you've posted conforms to the code you're actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through your code one line at a time using [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html).  Run `python -m pdb urlGenerator.py` and follow the instructions for using `pdb` in the linked page.

If you step through your code line by line you can immediately see that the line

```
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

is failing to return something useful:

```
(pdb) print(data)
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;economictimes&#46;indiatimes&#46;com&#47;archive&#46;cms" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;6057c817&#46;1508411706&#46;1c3ffe4
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It seems that they are not allowing access by Python's `urllib`.  As pointed out in the comments you really shouldn't be using `urllib` anyways--Scrapy is already adept at dealing with this.

A lot of the rest of your code is clearly broken as well.  For example this line:

```
months = hxs.xpath('//ul/li/a').re('http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms/\\d+-\\d+/news.cms')
```

returns an empty list even given the real HTML from this site.  If you look at the HTML it's clearly in a table, not unsorted lists (`<ul>`).  You also have the URL format wrong.  Instead something like this would work:

```
months = response.xpath('//table//tr//a/@href').re(r'/archive/year-\d+,month-\d+.cms')
```

If you want to build a web scraper, rather than starting from some code you found (that isn't even correct) and trying to blindly modify it, try following the [official tutorial for Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and start with some *very simple* examples, then build up from there.  For example:

```
class EtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'et'
    start_urls = ["https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms"]

    def parse(self, response):
        months = response.xpath('//table//tr//a/@href').re(r'/archive/year-\d+,month-\d+.cms')
        for month in months:
            self.logger.info(month)

process = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(EtSpider)
process.start()
```

This runs correctly, and you can clearly see it finding the correct URLs for the individual months, as printed to the log.  Now you can go from there and use *callbacks*, as explained in the documentation, to make further additional requests.

In the end you'll save yourself a lot of time and hassle by reading the docs and getting some understanding of what you're doing rather than taking some dubious code off the internet and trying to shoehorn it into your problem.